# Using Python Imaging Library (PIL) to open images with different bitsizes

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, bit-depth

I'm using PIL to open and manipulate a large selection of images.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
for image in os.listdir():
    im = Image.open(image)
    # do manipulations
```

For image with a bit depth of 24, this works. For images with a bit depth of 36 or 48, this fails.

How can I open images that do not have a bit depth of 24?

Comment: Based on the documentation, it looks like PIL only handles up to 32 bit encodings.

Comment: Ah. Could you link that part of the docs? I coudn't find it myself.

Comment: I based it off of this: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm#mode.  The only enabled modes are a max of 32 bit depth.

Comment: See also https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1888